# Phonegap - How to insert a frame template after take a picture ? it mean is : take a picture - select frame template - save image

Tags: cordova, camera

I have a problem in phonegap when i take a picture, edit(insert frame template) and save picture after edit. 
Do you known any library/plugin which support insert a frame template after take a picture in phonegap ?

Thanks!

Comment: frame template means...??you need the image to be shown in one img tag?

Comment: when i take a picture i want to select a frame which is available.